# "loop:" in Java code. What is this, and why does it compile?

Tags: java, labeled-statements

This code just made me stare at my screen for a few minutes:

```
loop:
for (;;) {
    // ...
}
```

([line 137 here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~play-developers/play/1.0/annotate/head:/framework/src/play/templates/TemplateCompiler.java#L137))

I have never seen this before, and I had no idea Java has a "loop" keyword (NetBeans doesn't even color it like a keyword), and it does compile fine with JDK 6.

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

It is not a `keyword` it is a `label`.

Usage:

```
    label1:
    for (; ; ) {
        label2:
        for (; ; ) {
            if (condition1) {
                // break outer loop
                break label1;
            }
            if (condition2) {
                // break inner loop
                break label2;
            }
            if (condition3) {
                // break inner loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7).

Comment: Worth mentioning, as the OP might not be familiar with the goto/label concept, that it's generally regarded as a bad practice, except in very particular situations (for instance, for shortcutting multiple nested loops).

Comment: @haylem true, but I would go further: multiple nested loops are usually a bad practice, too. Whenever I used loop labels, I eventually refactored the code so I didn't need them. There is always a better way than that.

Answer (score 77):

As other posters have said, it is a label, not a keyword. Using labels allows you to do things like:

```
outer: for(;;) {
   inner: for(;;) {
     break outer;
   }
}
```

This allows for breaking of the outer loop.

[Link to documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7).

Answer (score 31):

The question is answered, but as a side note:

I have heard of interview questions a la "Why is this Java code valid?" (stripped the simpler example; here's the meaner one, thx Tim Büthe):

```
url: http://www.myserver.com/myfile.mp3
downLoad(url);
```

Would you all know what this code is (apart from awful)?

Solution: two labels, `url` and `http`, a comment `www.myserver.com/myfile.mp3` and a method call with a parameter that has the same name (`url`) as the label. Yup, this compiles (if you define the method call and the local variable elsewhere).

Comment: FYI you don't need the loop, a ; in the next line is enough

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I think there were no loops in the question. I'll edit my answer (I was never asked this question but the interviewer was a former colleague of mine)

Answer (score 16):

That's not a keyword, it's a label. It's meant to be used with the `break` and `continue` keywords inside nested loops:

```
outer:
for(;;){
    inner:
    for(;;){
        if(){
            break inner; // ends inner loop
        } else {
            break outer; // ends outer loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `inner` label is useless here, `break;` is enough

Comment: If there are two ways to break the loop, I appreciate the `inner` label for clarity.

Comment: @gertas: I think he's just demonstrating the point. But per Steve Jackson, it might be a good idea to say it for self-documentation purposes anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a keyword; it's a [label](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#78993).

It allows you to go a labeled `break` and labeled `continue`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a break point label, to allow you to break out of a specified loop, rather than simply the innermost one you happen to be in.

It's used on [line 148](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~play-developers/play/1.0/annotate/head:/framework/src/play/templates/TemplateCompiler.java#L148).

Answer (score 4):

This is really a reply to seanizer's comment on org.life.java's answer, but I wanted to put in some code so I couldn't use the comment feature.

While it is very rare that I find a use for "break label", it does happen occassionally. The most common case is when I am searching for something that is in a structure requiring a nested loop to search, like:

```
search:
for (State state : stateList)
{
  for (City city : state.cityList)
  {
    if (city.zipcode.equals(wantZip))
    {
      doSomethingTo(city);
      break search;
    }
  }
}
```

Usually in such cases I push the whole thing into a subroutine so that on a hit I can return the found object, and if it falls out the bottom of the loop I can return null to indicate a not found, or maybe throw an exception. But this is occasionally useful.

Frankly, I think the inventors of Java included this feature because between this and exception handling, they eliminated the last two legitimate uses for GOTO.

Very late addendum:

I saw a great gag line of code once. The programmer wrote:

```
http://www.example.com/xyz.jsp
for (Foo foo1 : foolist)
```

He didn't actually say "example.com" but our company's web site.

It gives the impression that there's a URL in the code. It compiles successfully, like it does something. But ... what does it do?

In reality it does nothing. "http:" is a label that he never references. Then the "//" makes the rest of the line a comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's a label, though look at the following example:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0
while (a<10){
    firstLoop:
    a++;
    while(true){
        b++
        if(b>10){
            break firstLoop;
        }
    }
 }
```

When `b>10` the execution flow goes to the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could write almost anything, as it is a label...
You have an example [here](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/tipjava-using-block-label-as-goto/)

Answer (score 1):

It is a label, and labels in Java can be used with the `break` and `continue` key words for additional control over loops.

Here it is explained in a rather good way:

*[Thinking in Java, break and continue](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ305_024.htm)*

Answer (score 1):

It is not a keyword, but a **label**. If inside the `for` loop you write `break loop;`, and you exit that loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is a label. Generally a label used in Java to transfer the control flow at desired location while all keywords, like continue and break, have a specified choice of location.