# Break statement inside two while loops

Tags: java, while-loop, break

Let's say I have this:

```java
while (a) {
  while (b) {
    if (b == 10) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:**  Will the break statement take me out of both loops or only from the inner one? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to break out from two nested while loop, you can use labels...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your example break statement will take you out of while(b) loop

```
while(a) {

   while(b) {

      if(b == 10) {
         break;
      }
   }  
   // break will take you here.
}
```

Comment: What if I want also to break while-A?

Comment: @oneofakind you can use one more break statement where commented line is written

Comment: @oneofakind if you want to break out of both loops, put a label like "outer" on the first while, and then use "break outer;" to break to that level. See: https://gist.github.com/bseib/f5ee5c5baa31fa116feb715bd4037cb5

Answer (score 34):

It will break only the most immediate while loop. Using a label you can break out of both loops: take a look at this example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java)

---

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    outerloop:
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (i * j > 6) {
          System.out.println("Breaking");
          break outerloop;
        }
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

Comment: Its better to use flags instead of using labels, because it can easily lead to sphagetti code.

Comment: I would go even further and say that it's better to use functions and simply return from inner loop.

Answer (score 12):

Only from the inner one. Use **labeled break** if you wish to break to specific loop

```
label1:
for(){
  label2:
  for(){
      if(condition1)
      break label1;//break outerloop

      if(condition2)
      break label2;//break innerloop
  }
}
```

**Also See**

- [labeled break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf/3821841#3821841)

Answer (score 6):

```
while (a) {

   while (b) {

      if (b == 10) {
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

In the above code you will break the **inner most loop** where (ie. `immediate loop`) where `break` is used.

You can **break both the loops at once** using the `break` with `label`

```
label1: 
while (a) {

   while (b) {

      if (b == 10) {
          break label1;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

@Abhishekkumar

Break keyword has it's derived root from C and Assembly, and Break it's sole purpose to passes control out of the compound statement i.e. Loop, Condition, Method or Procedures.

Please refer these...

http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html#break

http://www.functionx.com/cpp/keywords/break.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_statement#Early_exit_from_loops

So, if you want to get out of Two loops at same time then you've to use two Breaks, i.e. one in inner loop and one in outer loop.

But you want to stop both loop at same time then you must have to use exit or return.

Answer (score 5):

It will break out of the loop that immediately encloses it.

You can however, break to a label:

```
myLabel:

while(a) {    
    while(b) {    
        if(b == 10)
            break myLabel;
    }
}
```

I don't generally like to use this pattern because it easily leads to spaghetti code. Use an unlabeled break or a flag to terminate your loop.

Answer (score 2):

As a curious note, in PHP the break statement accept a numeric parameter which tells how many outer loops you want to break, like this:

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
   switch ($i) {
      case 5:
         echo "At 5<br />\n";
         break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
      case 10:
         echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
         break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
      default:
         break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can raise a flag to pass the information to the outer while loop. In this case the information can be stored in a variable `breakOuterLoopFlag` and the outer while loop acts according to this information.
See pseudo code below:

```
int breakOuterLoopFlag = 0;

while(a){
   
  while(b){
      if(b == 10) {
        breakOuterLoopFlag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }

   if(breakOuterLoopFlag == 1) {
     break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `break` statement will take you out of the innermost loop enclosing that `break` statement.

In the example the inner while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The java break statement **won't** take you out of multiple nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Only the inner loop of course.