# What does the colon mean in Java?

Tags: java

What does the colon mean in Java?  I have this:

```
public static List<String> findAllAnagrams(List<String> words) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(String i : words){
        for (String j : words){
            if (result.contains(i)) {
                break;
            }
            else if (i == j) {

            } else {
                if (areAnagrams(i,j)){
                    result.add(i);
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }          
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is known as a for-each loop, you might want to google it and until now, none of the answers has named it yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Java for each loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: The answers to this questions seem not to be complete: What is this: import hudson.model.SCMS; (...)
SCMS: for (SCM scm : scmTriggerItem.getSCMs()) {something();}?

Answer (score 12):

It means one thing, it is an enhanced for loop.

```
for (String i: words)
```

means the same things as

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    //
}
```

**Joshua Bloch**, in Item 46 of his worth reading **Effective Java**, says the following:

> The for-each loop, introduced in release 1.5, gets rid of the clutter and the opportunity for error by hiding the iterator or index variable completely. The resulting idiom applies equally to collections and arrays:
>
> The preferred idiom for iterating over collections and arrays

```
for (Element e : elements) {
    doSomething(e);
}
```

> When you see the colon (:), read it as “in.”
> Thus, the loop above reads as “for each element e in elements.” Note that there is no performance penalty for using the for-each loop, even for arrays. In fact, it may offer a slight performance advantage over an ordinary for loop in some circumstances, as it computes the limit of the array index only once. While you can do this by hand (Item 45), programmers don’t always do so.

Comment: It _acts_ the same, but are they for the JVM really exact the same?

Comment: no they are not the same. The foreach is used with collections where   the length of the loop can be inferred from the number of elements available on the collection. You can do it, either way but foreach is syntactic sugar of exploiting collections.

Comment: In that case, could you include that into your answer? The OP is probably not an experienced Java developer, and I think it's best to learn correct things from the beginning.

Comment: Surely "for(String i: words)" doesn't mean the same thing as a for loop with "int i". Perhaps "for(int k = 0....){ String i = words[k]; // }"

Comment: It does not mean just "one" thing.  It is also used in java assertions

assert message.equals("Success") : "Wrong message. Expected: Success.   Actual: [" + message + "]";

Answer (score 4):

```
(String i : words)
```

For each item in `words`

: to indicate iterator item and item as `i`

so to answer - it represents for-each loop

Answer (score 2):

colon in [for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) is part of syntax, colon also appears with [label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf/3821841#3821841)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think **colon(:)** means anything particularly. It's just how Java designers thought to delimit **parameter** and **expression** inside improved for loop.

```
for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement
```

Check Language specification for same : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Answer (score 0):

It is for-each loop. When you see the colon (:) read it as "in"
You can find very good explanation in Oracle docs with included examples, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)