# Unfamiliar piece of enhanced for loop syntax

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the job of going through another's code and I'm trying to figure it all out when I came across this for loop.

```
//I don't understand the purpose of assetLoop
assetLoop: for (AssetObject asset : assets) {

     //Some code
}
```

I've never seen this syntax and I can't find any reference to it anywhere through my google searches.  Can anyone tell me what assetLoop: is doing?  Or simply give me the name of this concept so I can do some non-mindless googling and read about it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a label.

It allows you to write `break assetLoop` from a nested loop to break out of the outer loop.

It's essentially a limited form of `goto`, and is rarely used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf/3821841#3821841

Comment: Why is it rarely used?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GotoConsideredHarmful

Answer (score 0):

It's a label. You can put them on any statement. `break assetLoop;` will break out of that loop, even if the `break` statement is within another `for`, `while`, `do`-`while` or `switch` statement. Similarly `continure assetLoop;` will jump to the next iteration of the loop.