# How to additionally iterate inside the loop for(String s : st) in java?

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iterator

I am iterating over a vector of string as:

```
for(String s : st){
    while(s.equals("a")) //just an example, not exactly this required
    {
        //go to next element : How to do this?
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

How to iterate over next elements within the for(:) loop?

**EDIT:**

As many asked the logic of while,

the vector of string is basically containing single words of a sentence and I have to collapse Noun Phrases in the sentence, e.g. if there is a sentence like "Robert Sigwick is going home". so right now st[0] has "Robert" and st[1] has "Sigwick". After the processing I have to make st[0] = "Robert Sigwick".

So my code is somewhat like:

```
for(String s : st){
        string newEntry = "";
        while(getPOS(s).equals("NNP")) 
        {
            newEntry += s;
            // HERE I WANT THE HELP : something like s = getNext();
        }
        if(!newEntry.equals(""))
            result.add(newEntry);
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide clarification on your question. People are making a lot of assumptions right now.

Comment: I saw those responses, and so I have added the explanation few minutes before. Thanks!!

Comment: I still don't understand why you need an inner while loop... what is `getPos(s)`? You've explained the problem, but I think you need to explain the code you've written so far. The answer to your current question is no, you can't. There's a contract with a for loop that it will iterate all entries, you can't mess with the iterator that it's using outside of regular loop constructs.

Comment: getPOS(s) is a function to get Part of Speech(like NNP - noun phrase etc.) for that word. See a demo at [link](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/pos/?id=4)

Anyhow, the question was put as I wondered whether there is a way for it, and you answered that "There's a contract with a for loop that it will iterate all entries". Thanks!!

I got my work done by conventional for loop, and doing `i++` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop labels with continue

```
OUTER:
for(String s : st){
    while(s.equals("a")) //just an example, not exactly this required
    {
        //go to next element : How to do this?
        continue OUTER;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

NOTE: The loop label is only necessary if you have a nested loop. If the while should be an if-statement then a simple `continue;` will work.

**also** if it's an if-statement there could be even better ways. Consider:

```
for(String s : st){
    if(!s.equals("a")) //just an example, not exactly this required
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the whole method goes one level deeper. It's a preference thing.

More on loop labels: ["loop:" in Java code. What is this, why does it compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf)

Comment: `while` doesn't really make sense there. That certainly should be an `if`.

Comment: Now is more complete than mine. :)

Comment: @RohitJain there could be missing logic that we don't see. In any case this covers it either way.

Comment: Edited with explanation of my logic - the reason why I am using while

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String s : st){
    if(s.equals("a")) //just an example, not exactly this required
    {
        //go to next element : How to do this?
       continue;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: OP has a while loop. If they miswrote that then this is correct, but this doesn't answer the question as currently asked

Comment: Edited with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain why you need a `while` loop. You cannot go to next element this way.

Comment: Edited with explanation of my logic.