# How do I iterate through a LinkedList and retrieve the index of the first occurrence of a number of a nonzero number?

Tags: java, for-loop

If I have a list like

```
[0,0,5,7,9]
```

I want to get the index position of the number "5", which is 2, and have it stop printing after that.

I've tried doing this, but it will print out 2,3, and 4. Is there a way to have it stop printing after it finds the number "5"?

```
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    list.add(0);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(9);


    for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) != 0){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you need to call `break;` after condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following keyword will break the execution of loop

```
break;
```

---

**Also See**

- ["loop:" in Java code. What is this, why does it compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile/3821841#3821841)

Comment: Thank you. This has been bothering me for some time.

Comment: Of course. I just have to wait a few minutes before doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Just break the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i) != 0){
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to break when it finds `5` not for first non zero find

Comment: The question title is how to "retrieve the index of the first occurrence of a number of a nonzero number". In this case it happens to be 5.

Comment: nevermind, there is a little conflict _Is there a way to have it stop printing after it finds the number "5"?_

Answer (score 0):

This could also be achieved using a `while` loop..
For example, some pseudocode:

```
int count = 0     
while (keepTesting != true && count < size of the list)
{
    check integer at index [count]
    if (integer at index [count] != 0)
        set keepTesting to false
    increment count by 1  
}
```

You could choose any looping mechanism essentially to solve this problem..