# Java - Continous loop from the switch cases. What have I done wrong here?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Below is my code for one of my small projects. I have written what is required however its either I am missing something or haven't put a valid code to stop the continous looping with the println"Enter your keyword here". Can someone find my fault in this source code. What am I doing wrong here? I keep getting asked "Enter your keyword" question after I choose the exit option.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JobApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Job Search Portal");
        System.out.println("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ");
        System.out.println("name - To Enter Your Name:  ");
        System.out.println("dob - To Enter Your Date of Birth:  ");
        System.out.println("profession - To enter your profession");
        System.out.println("years - To enter the number of years you've workd");
        System.out.println("income - To enter your income from previous employer");

        String keyword = null;
        String name = null;
        String dob = null;
        String profession = null;
        int years = 0;
        long income = 0;
        String exit = null;

        do {
            System.out.println("\nEnter your keyword here");
            keyword = input.next();

            switch (keyword.toLowerCase()) {

                case "name":
                    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
                    name = input.next();
                    break;
                case "dob":
                    System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth");
                    dob = input.next();
                    break;
                case "profession":
                    System.out.println("Please enter your profession");
                    profession = input.next();
                    break;
                case "years":
                    System.out.println("Please enter the number of years experience you have");
                    years = input.nextInt();
                    if (years >= 2) {
                        if (years > 40) System.out.println("You are too old ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You are in experienced");
                    }
                    break;

                case "income":
                    System.out.println("Please enter your previous income");
                    income = input.nextLong();
                    break;

                case "exit":
                    System.out.println("The following are your details!");
                    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                    System.out.println("Date of Birth: " + dob);
                    System.out.println("Profession: " + profession);
                    System.out.println("Experience: " + years + " years");
                    System.out.println("Yearly Salary: K" + income);
                    System.out.println("We will get back to you soon!");
                    System.out.println("Good luck!");break;

                default: System.out.println("Enter a valid choice!");

        }

    }while(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You never break out of the do-while(true) loop.

Comment: Yes, you break out of the switch block, but that's it. Don't do `while (true)`. Instead use a sentinel value to help you break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use label for loops as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile).

In your example:

```
mainLoop: do {
//and then
break mainLoop;
```

However in my opinion changing condition in main loop would be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this keeps happening is because you're running it infinitely with your current condition of `while(true)`. You need some condition to exit your while loop. Looking at your code, it looks like you want to stop asking questions after the user types in `exit`. Change your `while` condition to this:

```
while(keyword.toLowerCase().compareTo("exit") != 0);
```

or (as @Tom pointed out), better yet:

```
 while (!keyword.toLowerCase().equals("exit"));
```

This will guarantee that it runs at least once, and will exit when the user types in `exit`. Cheers!

Comment: Why should someone use `.compareTo("exit") != 0`? When you want to check if a String is unequal to another one, then use `while(!keyword.toLowerCase().equals("exit"));`

Answer (score 0):

instead of While(true) use flag variable to control the loop.

i have rectify your code.. you can check it out.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JobApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Job Search Portal");
    System.out.println("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ");
    System.out.println("name - To Enter Your Name:  ");
    System.out.println("dob - To Enter Your Date of Birth:  ");
    System.out.println("profession - To enter your profession");
    System.out.println("years - To enter the number of years you've workd");
    System.out.println("income - To enter your income from previous employer");

    String keyword = null;
    String name = null;
    String dob = null;
    String profession = null;
    int years = 0;
    long income = 0;
    String exit = null;

    int flag=0;

    do {
        System.out.println("\nEnter your keyword here");
        keyword = input.next();

        switch (keyword.toLowerCase()) {

            case "name":
                System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
                name = input.next();
                break;
            case "dob":
                System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth");
                dob = input.next();
                break;
            case "profession":
                System.out.println("Please enter your profession");
                profession = input.next();
                break;
            case "years":
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of years experience you have");
                years = input.nextInt();
                if (years >= 2) {
                    if (years > 40) System.out.println("You are too old ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You are in experienced");
                }
                break;

            case "income":
                System.out.println("Please enter your previous income");
                income = input.nextLong();
                break;

            case "exit":
                System.out.println("The following are your details!");
                System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                System.out.println("Date of Birth: " + dob);
                System.out.println("Profession: " + profession);
                System.out.println("Experience: " + years + " years");
                System.out.println("Yearly Salary: K" + income);
                System.out.println("We will get back to you soon!");
                System.out.println("Good luck!");
        flag=1;
        break;

            default: System.out.println("Enter a valid choice!");

    }

}while(flag == 0);
}
}
```