# Why is my text parser getting into an infinite loop despite the loop being explicitly broken?

Tags: java, parsing

I have been working on a utility to parse text files in the format used by Paradox Interactive in their grand strategy games to be used with a visual-based modding tool I am also developing. I have a mostly-implemented, crude, early version of the parser written out and it is mostly working as intended. This is my second attempt at writing a text parser (the first, which ended up working just fine, parsed a subset of XML).

I speed-wrote my parser on the 9th and have spent all weekend trying to debug it, but all my efforts have failed. I have tracked the issue down to the 3rd line of `nextChar()`. It was throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error with a crazy small number (in the -2 millions). After I added a bounds check the program just... continues. It reads all the information as needed, it just doesn't ever exit the parse loop.

The format is basically this:

```
car = {
    model_year = 1966
    model_name = "Chevy"
    components = {
        "engine", "frame", "muffler"
    }
}
```

though I have yet to add support for nested lists like I plan, so my test string is:

```
car = {
    model_year = 1966
    model_name = "Chevy"
}
```

For both my understanding and anybody who would see my code, I tried to generously comment my code where I thought it might be necessary, though if any clarification is needed I would be happy to provide it.

My code:

```
/**
 * Parses text files in the format used by Paradox Interactive in their computer games EUIV, CK2, and Stellaris.
 * 
 * @author DJMethaneMan 
 * @date 12/9/2016
 */
public class Parser
{
    private int pos, line, len, depth;
    public String text;
    private char[] script; //TODO: Initialize in the parse method

    public Parser()
    {
        pos = 0;
        line = 1;
        len = 0;
        depth = 0;
        text = "car = {\n" +
               "    model_year = 1966 \n" +
               "    model_name = \"Chevy\"\n" +
               "}\u0003";
        //text = "Hello World";
        //Car c = new Car();
        //parse(text, c);
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        Car c = new Car();
        Parser p = new Parser();
        p.parse(p.text, c);
        System.out.println("The model name is " + c.model_name);
        System.out.println("The model year is " + c.model_year);
    }

    //TODO: Work
    public void parse(String text, Parseable parsed)
    {
        char[] script = text.toCharArray();
        this.script = script;
        boolean next_char = false;
        PARSE_LOOP:while(true)
        {
            char c;
            if(next_char)
            {
                c = nextChar();
            }
            else
            {
                c = script[0];
                next_char = true;
            }

            switch(c)
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                case 'B':
                case 'b':
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                case 'G':
                case 'g':
                case 'H':
                case 'h':
                case 'I':
                case 'i':
                case 'J':
                case 'j':
                case 'K':
                case 'k':
                case 'L':
                case 'l':
                case 'M':
                case 'm':
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                case 'O':
                case 'o':
                case 'P':
                case 'p':
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                case 'R':
                case 'r':
                case 'S':
                case 's':
                case 'T':
                case 't':
                case 'U':
                case 'u':
                case 'V':
                case 'v':
                case 'W':
                case 'w':
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
                case 'Z':
                case 'z':
                case '_'://TODO: HERE
                    if(depth > 0) //
                    {
                        parsed.parseRead(buildWordToken(true), this);//Let the class decide how to handle this information. Best solution since I do not know how to implement automatic deserialization.
                    }
                    continueUntilChar('=', false); //A value must be assigned because it is basically a key value pair with {} or a string or number as the value
                    skipWhitespace();//Skip any trailing whitespace straight to the next token.
                    break;
                case '{':
                    depth++;
                    break;
                case '}':
                    depth--;
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    line++;
                    break;
                case ' ':
                case '\t':
                    skipWhitespace();
                    break;
                case '\u0003': //End of Text Character... Not sure if it will work in a file...
                    break PARSE_LOOP;
            }
        }
    }

    //Returns a string from the next valid token
    public String parseString()
    {
        String retval = "";
        continueUntilChar('=', false);
        continueUntilChar('"', false);
        retval = buildWordToken(false);
        continueUntilChar('"', false); //Don't rewind because we want to skip over the quotation and not append it.
        return retval;
    }

    //Returns a double from the next valid token
    public double parseNumber()
    {
        double retval = 0;
        continueUntilChar('=', false); //False because we don't want to include the = in any parsing...
        skipWhitespace(); //In case we encounter whitespace.
        try
        {
            retval = Double.parseDouble(buildNumberToken(false));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("A token at line " + line + " is not a valid number but is being passed as such.");
        }
        return retval;
    }


    /**********************************Utility Methods for Parsing****************************************/

    protected void continueUntilChar(char target, boolean rewind)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            char c = nextChar();
            if(c == target)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(rewind)
        {
            pos--;
        }
    }

    protected void skipWhitespace()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            char c = nextChar();
            if(!Character.isWhitespace(c))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        pos--;//Rewind because by default parse increments pos by 1 one when fetching nextChar each iteration.
    }

    protected String buildNumberToken(boolean rewind)
    {
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
        String retval = "INVALID_NUMBER";
        char token_start = script[pos];
        System.out.println(token_start + " is a valid char for a word token."); //Print it.
        token.append(token_start);
        while(true)
        {
            char c = nextChar();
            if(Character.isDigit(c) || (c == '.' && (Character.isDigit(peek(1)) || Character.isDigit(rewind(1))))) //Makes sure things like 1... and ...1234 don't get parsed as numbers.
            {
                token.append(c);
                System.out.println(c + " is a valid char for a word token."); //Print it for debugging
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }

    protected String buildWordToken(boolean rewind)
    {
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder(); //Used to build the token
        char token_start = script[pos]; //The char the parser first found would make this a valid token
        token.append(token_start); //Add said char since it is part of the token
        System.out.println(token_start + " is a valid char for a word token."); //Print it.
        while(true)
        {
            char c = nextChar();
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(c) || Character.isDigit(c) || c == '_')//Make sure it is a valid token for a word
            {
                System.out.println(c + " is a valid char for a word token."); //Print it for debugging
                token.append(c); //Add it to the token since its valid
            }
            else
            {
                if(rewind)//If leaving the method will make this skip over a valid token set this to true.
                {
                    //Rewind by 1 because the main loop in parse() will still check pos++ and we want to check the pos of the next char after the end of the token.
                    pos--;
                    break; //Leave the loop and return the token.
                }
                else //Otherwise
                {
                    break; //Just leave the loop and return the token.
                }
            }
        }
        return token.toString(); //Get the string value of the token and return it.
    }

    //Returns the next char in the script by amount but does not increment pos.
    protected char peek(int amount)
    {
        int lookahead = pos + amount; //pos + 1;
        char retval = '\u0003'; //End of text character
        if(lookahead < script.length)//Make sure lookahead is in bounds.
        {
            retval = script[lookahead]; //Return the char at the lookahead.
        }
        return retval; //Return it.
    }

    //Returns the previous char in the script by amount but does not decrement pos.
    //Basically see peek only this is the exact opposite.
    protected char rewind(int amount)
    {
        int lookbehind = pos - amount; //pos + 1;
        char retval = '\u0003';
        if(lookbehind > 0)
        {
            retval = script[lookbehind];
        }
        return retval;
    }

    //Returns the next character in the script.
    protected char nextChar()
    {
        char retval = '\u0003';
        pos++;
        if(pos < script.length && !(pos < 0))
        {
            retval = script[pos]; //It says this is causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with the following message. Shows a very large (small?) negative number.
        }
        return retval;
    }
}

//TODO: Extend
interface Parseable
{
    public void parseRead(String token, Parser p);
    public void parseWrite(ParseWriter writer);
}


//TODO: Work on
class ParseWriter
{

}

class Car implements Parseable
{
    public String model_name;
    public int model_year;

    @Override
    public void parseRead(String token, Parser p)
    {
        if(token.equals("model_year"))
        {
            model_year = (int)p.parseNumber();
        }
        else if(token.equals("model_name"))
        {
            model_name = p.parseString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void parseWrite(ParseWriter writer)
    {
        //TODO: Implement along with the ParseWriter
    }
}
```

Comment: First guess from glancing at the code is that no `breaks` are actually being hit. Thus, causing infinite loop.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you try to read the value of model year and model name before advancing past the equals sign.

Comment: @DavidConrad No, it reads "car", since the depth is greater than 0 (eg we already encountered at least one `{`) then we read the information. The data is basically a key value pair, and I just skip over the first key and parse the values after the `{` directly into my `Car` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use of the labeled break statement `break PARSE_LOOP;` is generally considered bad practice. You are essentially writing a "goto" statement: whenever the `break PARSE_LOOP;` condition is hit, it jumps back to the beginning of the while loop (because that's where you wrote `PARSE_LOOP:`). This is probably the reason for your infinite loop. I also don't understand why you would restart a while loop that is already infinite (`while true`).

Change your code to:

```
 public void parse(String text, Parseable parsed)
        {
            char[] script = text.toCharArray();
            this.script = script;
            boolean next_char = false;
            boolean parsing = true;

            while(parsing)
            {
                char c;
                if(next_char)
                {
                    c = nextChar();
                }
                else
                {
                    c = script[0];
                    next_char = true;
                }

                switch(c)
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'b':
                    case 'C':
                    case 'c':
                    case 'D':
                    case 'd':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'F':
                    case 'f':
                    case 'G':
                    case 'g':
                    case 'H':
                    case 'h':
                    case 'I':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'J':
                    case 'j':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'k':
                    case 'L':
                    case 'l':
                    case 'M':
                    case 'm':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'n':
                    case 'O':
                    case 'o':
                    case 'P':
                    case 'p':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'r':
                    case 'S':
                    case 's':
                    case 'T':
                    case 't':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'u':
                    case 'V':
                    case 'v':
                    case 'W':
                    case 'w':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'x':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'y':
                    case 'Z':
                    case 'z':
                    case '_'://TODO: HERE
                        if(depth > 0) //
                        {
                            parsed.parseRead(buildWordToken(true), this);//Let the class decide how to handle this information. Best solution since I do not know how to implement automatic deserialization.
                        }
                        continueUntilChar('=', false); //A value must be assigned because it is basically a key value pair with {} or a string or number as the value
                        skipWhitespace();//Skip any trailing whitespace straight to the next token.
                        break;
                    case '{':
                        depth++;
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        depth--;
                        break;
                    case '\n':
                        line++;
                        break;
                    case ' ':
                    case '\t':
                        skipWhitespace();
                        break;
                    case '\u0003': //End of Text Character... Not sure if it will work in a file...
                        parsing = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was under the impression that labled loops were just a way to conveniently and terse way to say "break all loops up to the labled one". Is my understanding not correct?

Comment: @DJMethaneMan I don't understand what you're asking. All the "break parse_loop" statement does, is when that statement is executed, it jumps to the section of code labeled "PARSE_LOOP:" which is right before your while statement. So your while statement gets executed again. Do as Bill K and myself suggested; get rid of the break PARSE_LOOP: and change it to use a boolean instead. I'll edit my answer to reflect this suggestion shortly.

Comment: Not arguing that I should probably use a boolean, but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3821841/4326020) the labeled loop and all interior loops are immediately broken. As a side note - I had absolutely no idea that using a label would make somebody scratch their head... I guess you learn something every day. I thought it was common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Put a debug statement in to prove that it's hitting your break, I'm guessing it's not (Although it could be the break label--I haven't had reason to look into that construct since I first learned java a couple decades ago).  I have a couple suggestions though...

I'd use isAlpha instead of that part of the switch.  Cleaner, shorter, probably about as efficient and language-agnostic.

Instead of using the break label (Which is very uncommon), You might want to use boolean parsing=true;while(parsing)... instead.  It's not really wrong to use the break label, but...  Anything that causes the next guy to spend a minute or two scratching his head is a few minutes wasted.

Comment: Huh? My understanding is that his break PARSE_LOOP statement is causing the program to restart the while(true) loop instead of exiting it. In any case we're agreed that it's confusing and unnecessary. \

Comment: Could be, as I said haven't looked at that syntax in 20 years.

Comment: @KyleM It's a break, not a continue.

Comment: If I remove the `&& !(pos < 0)` from the bounds check in `nextChar()` then it will run for a bit and then throw an exception because pos somehow ends up with a negative value. So I know the error might be in one of the methods where `pos--` is called. I reviewed these methods and...nothing. I still cannot see why it is not falling through to `break PARSE_LOOP`

Comment: I believe file positions are set to -1 when you read past the end of the file as a simplified way to tell you that you are done reading the file without throwing an exception.