# Comparing string to 2d string array, compares only the last value of the array

Tags: java, android

When I compare  demDigits.equals(Numbers[i][j]) the if is only true with the last value in the 2d array which is 666, every other value from 111-555 is false. Can't figure out why

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText digits;
    EditText console;
    Button press;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[][] Numbers = {
                {"111", "222"},
                {"333", "444"},
                {"555", "666"}
        };
        digits = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        console = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        press = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String demDigits = digits.getText().toString();

                for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < Numbers[i].length; j++ )
                    {

                        if (demDigits.equals(Numbers[i][j]))
                        {
                            console.setText("works");
                            //break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.setText("nope");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you `break` inside that loop you are only breaking out of the inner loop. Not sure if that's what you want, but you can use [labeled loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3821827/7366707) to break out of the outer loop.

Comment: Thats commented, I tried stopping the loop when equals would be true but that didn't help. No need for a break solution.

Comment: I am talking about the fact that you aren't stopping the whole loop with that break statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be getting more than you bargained for from your **digits.getText()** method as **@Ekundayo** has pointed out within a comment of the code he posted. Check it, you should get a string length of 3 in order to make a proper comparison:

```
final String demDigits = digits.getText().toString();

// Read LogCat to see output with method below
// or use whatever you want to display desired 
// output.
Log.d("demDigits", "demDigits Length = " + demDigits.length());
```

It's never a bad thing to trim User input since additional spaces are easy for a User to apply during that input. For some people it's a downright habit. As **@Ekundayo** has already suggested:

```
final String demDigits = digits.getText().toString().trim();
```

should take care of that issue.

Since you have a commented **break** statement within your code it is naturally assumed that you would like to break out of your **for** loops once a successful comparison has been made. This makes total sense since it's a waste of time to process any further unless of course you actually want to. As **@1blustone** has already pointed out within his comments, to properly break out of both inner and outer **for** loops you're going to need more than one **break** statement, you'll need one for each loop. Here is how you can accomplish this:

```
final String demDigits = digits.getText().toString().trim();

for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
    boolean mustBreak = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < Numbers[i].length; j++ ) {
        if (demDigits.equals(Numbers[i][j])) {
            console.setText("works");
            mustBreak = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            console.setText("nope");
        }
    }
    if (mustBreak) { break; }
}
```

but for some reason, I think you already know this ;)

Comment: Thanks for explaining and solving my problem.