# Q: Doing multiple loops and multiple if-statements and if-else-statements | RENTAL CAR CALCULATOR PROJECT

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

my instructions on the project were as followed:

Instructions: Use a sentinel value loop. To create a basic Rental Car Calculator

Ask each user for:

Type of vehicle (May use something other than strings, such as: 1 for an economy, 2 for a sedan, etc.) Days rented Calculate the (For each customer):

Rental cost, Taxes, Total Due. There are three different rental options with separate rates: Economy @ 31.76, sedan @ 40.32, SUV @ 47.56. [Note: only whole day units to be considered (no hourly rates)].

Sales tax is = to 6% on the TOTAL.

Create summary data with:

The number of customers Total money collected. Also, Include IPO, algorithm, and desk check values (design documents).

{WHAT I HAVE GOING AND MY QUESTION(S)}

```
package tests;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String []args){
int count=0;
int days;
int cus;
int carType;
double dailyFee=0, nonTaxTotal, total,fullTotal=0;
boolean checkRunOrQuit = false, chooseTypeVehicle = false, numberOfDAysChosen = false;
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);


while ( !checkRunOrQuit ) {
    System.out.print("Press 1 to enter Rental Calculator or else press 0 to quit\n");
    System.out.println("Please only enter 1 or 0. Also, please only enter number(s) not letter(s)");
    try {
        cus=in.nextInt();
        switch ( cus ) {
            case 0: System.out.println("End of application");
                    System.exit(0); // This will actually end your application if the user enters 0, no need to verify later on
            break;
            case 1: checkRunOrQuit = true;
            break;
            default:
                    System.out.println("Number must be either 1 or 0");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry: ");
        in.next();
    }
}

while( !chooseTypeVehicle ) { // --> simplified comparison
    count++;
    System.out.print("What vehical would you like to rent?\n");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for an economy car");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");

    try {
        carType = in.nextInt();
        chooseTypeVehicle = true;
        switch ( carType ) {
            case 1: dailyFee = 31.76;
            break;
            case 2: dailyFee = 40.32;
            break;
            case 3: dailyFee = 47.56;
            break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Number must be 1-3\n");
                System.out.println("Please enter 1 for an economy car");
                System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car");
                System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");
                chooseTypeVehicle = false;
                break;
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
        in.next(); // -> you forgot this one.
    }
}

while ( !numberOfDAysChosen ) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of days rented. (Example; 3) : ");
        days = in.nextInt();
        if (days <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Number of days must be more than zero");
        } else {
            nonTaxTotal = (dailyFee * days);
            total = (nonTaxTotal * 1.06);
            fullTotal+=total;
            numberOfDAysChosen = true;
        }
    } catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
        in.next();
    }
}
in.close();
System.out.println("Count of customers : " + count);
System.out.printf("total of the Day : $ %.2f", fullTotal);
    }
}
```

1. How would I make this program loop back to prompting the user: "Press 1 to enter Rental Calculator or else press 0 to quit\". After the "days rented input is entered?

[Note: Once the days rented is input, I was wanting a total calculation but not a summary. However, I want the summary info when the program is exited.]

Comment: You need to be all your loops into a while loop.  it would be cleaner if you put each `while` loop into its own method

Comment: "How [do] I loop back...?" You just answered your own question: by using **a loop**

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I guess what I've been wondering is there any way to repeat the "while ( !checkRunOrQuit )" loop? being as there are multiple loops in that one?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have looked over it and it did help me to understand the looping process better thank you. However, it still did not solve my question that is posted. Still can not get multiple entries.

Comment: @ScaryWombat anytime i try to add in labels it prompts me a error when i try to break one saying that it is not found :/